# java painting rectangle using doubles

Tags: java, swing

I have a piece of code that prints a square to the screen.

```
g.fillRect(X,Y,squareSize,squareSize);
```

to get square size I am using:

```
int squareSize = (400/gridsize)-1;
```

where `gridsize` can be any number between 3-200

however if I go above 130 `squareSize` is always 1. Is there a version of the

```
g.fillRect
```

that uses a double rather than an integer value?

because if it rounds to 1 for anything above 130 there squares are all the same size whereas they should be different sizes depending.

so this is the issue in a visual form.

150by150

[image]

200 by 200

[image]

Comment: How do you imagine double coordinates representing a pixel?

Comment: ah ok I think I get it now...

Comment: You could have a look at `java.awt.Rectangle2D`

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a version of the `g.fillRect` that uses a double rather than an integer value?

If you read the documentation of `java.awt.Graphics` there is no `fillRect` that has double parameters.

If you really need to use double values you can use `Rectangle2D` and fill this shape using `fill(shape)` method.

```
double x = 0;
double y = 0;
double width = 100;
double height = 100;

Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height);

//java.awt.Graphics doesn't have fill(shape), so you need to cast it to Graphics2D
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

g2.fill(rect);
```

Anyway if you are trying to draw with subpixel precision you need to enable `RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE`. You can enable it like this

```
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The same problem exists *regardless* of your grid size, not just above 130.  Look at the first few values of your `squareSize` starting with 3.

```
for (int i = 3; i <= 10; i++) { // change 10 to 200 to see all relationships
     System.out.printf("Square Size = %3d, Grid Size = %3d%n", (400/i-1),i);
 }
```

prints

```
Square Size = 132, Grid Size =   3
Square Size =  99, Grid Size =   4
Square Size =  79, Grid Size =   5
Square Size =  65, Grid Size =   6
Square Size =  56, Grid Size =   7
Square Size =  49, Grid Size =   8
Square Size =  43, Grid Size =   9
Square Size =  39, Grid Size =  10
```

Your `squareSize` is fluctuating significantly as the `gridsize` steps by 1. As the divisor gets larger, the difference between successive squareSizes diminishes. If that isn't of concern why is the same square size for different grid sizes a concern? And how would a square size of `132` actually be used for a `gridSize` of `3`?  Lacking specific details about your task, I don't think that using sub-pixel accuracy is going to improve your game of life or make it easier to see the relative differences between grid sizes.  Perhaps prompting for a square size and then, using that, computing the appropriate grid size and any other required dimensions might be an alternative.